# What did my uncle want to write?

Tags: riddle, word, cipher, cryptic-clues

I've always been a writer as well as a puzzler, and my uncle shares that same fascination with both.

Recently, he shared with me a complex puzzle that he'd made when he was my age. He said that the solution was the kind of book he'd always wanted to write and publish.

I took a picture of the puzzle and uploaded it here, for any solvers to work on:

[image]

Can you help me figure out what kind of book my uncle had always wanted to write?

Comment: We have bits and pieces solved, can you add some hints for the other parts?

Answer (score 2):

## Partial answer - one section solved, one mostly solved

#### Bottom Right

> Here, PI can be filled into the blanks. Then, each set of letters can be pushed upwards one as indicated, and the blank can be filled to form a new word:
>  PIE, RIPE, PRICE, **RECIPE**.

#### Bottom Left

> Each of the left words is an anagram-plus-one-letter of the corresponding right word. In order:
>
>  THORN / HORN
>  DRAKES / ASKED
>  ETCHES / TECHS
>  ELECTRIC / CIRCLET
>  REVOIR / RIVER
>  STARTLE / RATTLE
>
>  This gives TREEOS, which anagrams to **STEREO**.

---

Thoughts on other sections:

> "parallax second" is likely cluing PARSEC.
>  The other two might be cluing words in the same way, and then the results could be combined together to get a word? "Within the false lies truth" seems to be indicating something like that: that the "wrong words" lead to the correct one. (This could mean that the answers to the clues are hidden inside the "not a..." text, which might make the second answer ITCH?)
>
>  The top section doesn't seem to be actual runes, for the most part. The dashes through the arrows indicate that those arrows should be considered differently from the rest (though I'm not quite sure how) -- that will likely be clear when we have more sections' answers (which are likely all six-letter words?).

Comment: I think the missing pair in the bottom left is rot13(RYRPGEVP/PVEPYRG), making the missing letter rot13(R).

Comment: @JeremyDover Oh, nice find - added!

Comment: Also, is it possible rot13(gur neebjf vaqvpngr n cngu guebhtu gur chmmyr, naq gur fvatyr unpx/qbhoyr unpx ba gur gjb neebjf pbzvat sebz gur gbc frpgvba vaqvpngr gur beqre va juvpu gurl'er hfrq?)

Comment: Hey there , The middle rght puzzle "In the false lies the truth " , I just thogut that 
Parsec is a gaming platform , also scratch is also related to gaming, what are your views the question setter Excited Raichu is also a role play gamer I think from his profile
couldn't tell what to do with mutlitple review , what are your views

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

Building on Deusovi's answer.

### Middle-Left Puzzle

A word used when introducing oneself

> "Nice TO meet you"

Half Greek, half French, half breed

> I don't really know, but maybe the author is half French, half Greek?  So I?

A salad base without you and me

> LETTUCE without "us" == LETT or LET

> TOILET ?

### Middle-Right Puzzle

Not a parallax second

> PARSEC

Not a simple scratch

> SCRAPE

Not multiple reviews

> RECAPS

Within the false lies truth

> I...don't know what this means yet.  The preceding word (from the bottom-right puzzle) is RECIPE.  These anagrams share all the same letters with RECIPE except I, E, A, S.  It could have something to do with that, or be entirely unrelated.

Comment: Thats a great amount of progress Thanx